# How to install OpenJDK-19 debug symbols on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, java, snap, openjdk, debug

I've installed OpenJDK-19 on Ubuntu 20.04 using `snap`. However, I'm not able to find the package in `snap` which corresponds to `openjdk-19-dbg` in `apt`, and I can't find OpenJDK-19 in `apt` at all.
Could you please tell me how to install the JVM debug symbols for OpenJDK-19 on Ubuntu 20.04?